# How can i save a value as a double in firestore web?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried going through the questions asked but i haven't found the right answer, i am trying to add a value as a double but its adding the data as a string.
this is my JavaScript

```
var Price = 0.0;

const priceValue = document.getElementById("price").value;
Price = priceValue;

database.collection("product").doc(uuidv4()).set({
            price: Price,
        });
```

and this is my html

```
<div class="inputfield">
          <label>Price</label>
          <input id="price" type="number" class="input">
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to the firestorm but to your handling of the input data, you see the value of the input field will always be of the string type like demonstrated in the snippet below

```js
function myFun() {
  const priceValue = document.getElementById("price").value;
  console.log(priceValue, typeof priceValue)
}
```

```html
<div class="inputfield">
  <label>Price</label>
  <input id="price" type="number" class="input" value="0.0">
  <button onClick="myFun()">Check type</button>
</div>
```

So in order to actually save a value as a number in firestorm you would first need to manually parse it.

```js
function myFun() {
  const priceValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
  console.log(priceValue, typeof priceValue)
}
```

```html
<div class="inputfield">
  <label>Price</label>
  <input id="price" type="number" class="input" value="0.0">
  <button onClick="myFun()">Check type</button>
</div>
```

`<input>` elements of type number are used to let the user enter a number. They include built-in validation to reject non-numerical entries, however the true value of the element will still be a string.